# Find an equation of the tangent line to the curve $y=x^3-3x+1$ at the given point $(2,3)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The only thing I know is that you must use the formula to find the slope of the tangent line, but I'm not quite sure on the steps to doing so.

Comment: The slope of the tangent line at a point $\langle x,f(x)\rangle$ is the value of the derivative at $x$, $f\,'(x)$; can you find $f\,'(x)$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Well, I'm not sure if this is in the ballpark,but I got x(x+2) for f′(x). Is this remotely close?

Comment: @Anon No, it's wrong: $f'(x)=3x^2-3$.

Comment: I’m afraid not: the derivative of $x^3$ is $3x^2$, the derivative of $3x$ is $3$, and the derivative of $1$ is $0$, so $f\,'(x)=3x^2-x$.

Comment: @Brian M.Scott May I ask what formula you're using? I've been using the only formula I've learned today for this type of equation, which is f(x)-f(a)/x-a. Using this, I've had no luck as to obtaining your answer. If it's not too much to ask, can you evaluate on your steps?

Comment: That quotient isn’t the derivative: the derivative of $f$ at $a$ is the **limit** of that quotient as $x\to a$. That is, $$f\,'(a)=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}\;.$$ One uses it to derive more useful computational formulas for the derivatives of various kinds of functions. One of those formulas is that the derivative of $x^3$ is $3x^2$; this comes from showing that $$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{x^3-a^3}{x-a}=3a^2\;.$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Given

$$
y=x^3-2x+1,
$$

we have that

$$
y'=3x^2-2.
$$

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of $f(x)=x^3-3x+1$ is $f'(x)=3x^{(3-1)}-3x^{(1-1)}+0=3x^2-3x^0=3x^2-3.$

This derivative was obtained because:

$a)$ The derivative of any constant is always $0$. (That's why the $1$ became $0$)

$b)$ The derivative of a "power term" like $x^n$ will be $nx^{n-1}.$ (That's why $x^3$ became $3x^2$ and that's why $-3x$ became $-3.$

If you do not want to use the derivative rules, you may proceed by First Principles Definition of a Derivative:

$$\lim _{h\to 0}\dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$